# Is it poor practice to have db and site on different vms on same physical box?

Tags: virtual-machines

I am not too familiar with how virtual machines work but I was planning to have two physical machines each with two virtual machines on each physical box.  What I wanted to setup is a test environment with a test IIS site and a test sql instance on one physical machine.  The other machine would have a vm for the prod iis site along with the database on another vm on this same box.

So you have the following:

physical machine 1 (test instance)

- 1 vm for iis
- 1 vm for sql server

physical machine 2 (prod instance)

- 1 vm for iis
- 1 vm for sql server

Is this considered bad practice, would it be better to have both vm's on a specific machine running database (sql server) for instance.  Or is what I have an ok setup?

Comment: The answer you got is good, but ultimately the answer is "it depends."

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not a poor practice. It is very common see it setup this way.

If you have both the database and web servers for the same environment on a single VMware server, one of the VMware servers can go down and one of the environments will still be available. Another benefit of having the entire test and production environments on different VMware servers is that high CPU usage on the test environment will not affect the production site.

If you set it up the other way, with both test and production would be unavailable if either VMware server went down.

Comment: how would both go down?  If I have production on one physical box seperated into two VM's: db, iis.  Another physical server for test with two vm's one for db and the other iis.  I don't see how if one physical server goes down both test and prod go down?  And we aren't using mysql - I mentioned sql server.

Comment: Either I did not explain myself correctly or something, what my vision is is 2 virtual machines on one physical server.  So there will be two physical servers.  Each physical server will have two vms on them.  One physical server will be production and on this server will be two vms: IIS, SQL SERVER.  Then we have another physical server that will be test.  On this physical server there will also be two virtual machines.  One of those vms will have IIS the other SQL Server, does this make sense ?

Comment: Yes, I was explaining that if you had them set up the other way it would be worse.

Comment: I had a SunFire 12k Unix server in a data center (huge $240,000 machine) that was divided into 2 logical servers.  It had 12 power supplies; 6 plugged into one power panel and 6 supposedly plugged into a separate power panel.  One day a power panel died and we then found out all 12 power supplies were plugged into the same power panel.

Comment: @Bart can you edit your answer such that you answer based on my recommendation not the opposite. I keep rereading this and it doesnt answer my question.